# Agregar propiedad a objeto de Eloquent en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, json, eloquent

Usando Laravel hago una consulta a una tabla llamada **Compras** que extrae los campos *id_compra, nombre_producto, precio, fecha_compra*, y los regresa en un objeto json, todo sale bien.

Lo que quiero hacer es agregar una propiedad final con el promedio de los precios de todos los registros extraídos

El código que uso en el controlador es

```
$resultado = Compras::select("id_compra","nombre_producto","precio","fecha_compra")->where("nota_venta","=","1");

return response()->json($resultado);
```

El objeto que deseo generar es como el siguiente:

```
[{id_compra:1, nombre_producto:"producto 1", precio:30,fecha_compra:"2018-08-18"},
{id_compra:2, nombre_producto:"producto 2", precio:45,fecha_compra:"2018-08-18"},
{id_compra:3, nombre_producto:"producto 3", precio:80,fecha_compra:"2018-08-18"},
{id_compra:4, nombre_producto:"producto 4", precio:70,fecha_compra:"2018-08-18"},
{"promedio_precio":56.25}]
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacer eso es usando el metodo `avg()`:

```
$resultado = Compras::select("id_compra","nombre_producto","precio","fecha_compra")->where("nota_venta","=","1");

$promedio = $resultado->avg('precio');

return response()->json([
    'resultado' => $resultado,
    'promedio' => $promedio,
]);
```

Acá tenes la documentación, [Método average() o avg()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-avg)

**## AGREGADO ##**
Ahí vi tu [solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178139/57312) y no pensé que era necesario que esté todo en la misma colección.
No es necesario que hagas tantos pasos para unir todo, directamente podés hacer:

```
$resultado = Compras::select("id_compra","nombre_producto","precio","fecha_compra")
                         ->where("nota_venta","=","1")
                         ->get();

$resultado->put('promedio', $resultado->avg('precio'));

return response()->json($resultado);
```

Espero te sirva mi nuevo aporte.

Comment: Buena respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu guía Maru

Comment: De nada, ahí te propuse algo mejor, usando el método `put()`, también podrías usar el método `push()` pero en este caso lo mejor creo que es put. pero mira esos métodos que son muy muy útiles. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a la respuesta de Maru Amallo me sirvió para buscar mas en la documentación y puede hacer el siguiente código:

```
$resultado = Compras::select("id_compra","nombre_producto","precio","fecha_compra")->where("nota_venta","=","1");

$promedio = $resultado->avg('precio');
$collection = collect([["promedio"=>$promedio]]);
$resultado = $resultado->concat($collection);
return response()->json($resultado);
```

Gracias

Comment: Seria genial si explicas por qué usaste concat y collect